# select maximums and minumums from the same table ordered by max / mins row-by row

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to solve followng with SQL (on Oracle DB)

TABLE A

```
COL1  COL2
a     1
b     84
c     5
d     90
e     9
f     11
g     22
```

I need to select from the table A as (select table A ordered by col2 DESCENDING criss-corss row-by-row WITH select table A ordered by col2  ASCENDING)

so that the row with maximum is followed by the row with mininimum and so on..

something like this:

```
COL1  COL2
d     90   (most extreme maximum(1))
a      1   (most extreme minimum(1))
b     84   (most extreme maximum(2))
c      5   (most extreme minimum(2))
g     22   (most extreme maximum(3))
e      9   (most extreme minimum(3))
f     11   .. and so on..
```

I can do it in PL/SQL but I need it in SQL.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select    col1, col2
from      a
order by  least ( row_number() over (order by col2 desc),
                  row_number() over (order by col2) + 0.5
                )
;
```

Comment: Window sort seems to be the most ellegant way to do it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
select a.*
from ((select a.*, row_number() over (order by col2 asc) as seqnum, 1 as ismax
       from a
      ) union all
      (select a.*, row_number() over (order by col2 desc) as seqnum, 0
       from a
      )
     ) a
order by seqnum, ismax desc;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, it works, but would it be possible to select it without  the reverse  (something like this): `code` C       COL2     SEQNUM      ISMAX
- ---------- ---------- ----------
a          1          1          1
d         90          1          0
c          5          2          1
b         84          2          0
e          9          3          1
g         22          3          0
f         11          4          1
`code` - damn I really do not know how to format the code in comment..

Comment: This will include every row from the original table TWICE. I don't think that was the assignment.

Comment: @mathguy . . . I find the question pretty clear that the rows *are* selected twice:  "select table A ordered by col2 DESCENDING criss-corss row-by-row WITH select table A ordered by col2 ASCENDING)".

Answer (score 1):

Build out a sorter:

```
with 
--your data
tableA as
  (select 'a' as col1, 1 as col2 from dual
   union all
   select 'b' as col1, 84 as col2 from dual
   union all
   select 'c' as col1, 5 as col2 from dual
   union all
   select 'd' as col1, 90 as col2 from dual
   union all
   select 'e' as col1, 9 as col2 from dual
   union all
   select 'f' as col1, 11 as col2 from dual
   union all
   select 'g' as col1, 22 as col2 from dual
   union all
   select 'e' as col1, 4 as col2 from dual),

--get your stats
  aggs as
  (select col1, min(col2) as col2, 2 as sorter from tableA group by col1
   union all
  select col1, max(col2) as col2, 1 as sorter from tableA group by col1
  order by sorter)
   select distinct col1, col2
   from aggs
   order by col1;
```

---

New answer below based on your comments

---

```
with aggs as
  (select col1, min(col2) as col2, 2 as sorter from 
  a   --your table name?
 group by col1
   union all
  select col1, max(col2) as col2, 1 as sorter from 
a   --your table name?
group by col1
  order by sorter)

   select distinct col1, col2
   from aggs
   order by col1;
```

Comment: It works as well but I need it on physical table:   CREATE TABLE "AOS_BT"."A" 
   ( "COL1" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
 "COL2" NUMBER
   ); 
Insert into AOS_BT.A (COL1,COL2) values ('a','1');
Insert into AOS_BT.A (COL1,COL2) values ('b','84');
Insert into AOS_BT.A (COL1,COL2) values ('c','5');
Insert into AOS_BT.A (COL1,COL2) values ('d','90');
Insert into AOS_BT.A (COL1,COL2) values ('e','9');
Insert into AOS_BT.A (COL1,COL2) values ('f','11');
Insert into AOS_BT.A (COL1,COL2) values ('g','22');

Comment: create table AOS_BT as

Comment: Sorry - posted that comment by mistake.  Just edit my code to point to your table instead of the WITH clause. I'll post that as a separate reply, can't format code in comments